# MS Visio OpenEx method, open method flags

Tags: vba, visio

[Documents.OpenEx method (Visio)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.documents.openex) can have some flags, what if I want to be hidden open a file that a user has already opened in Visio?

I tried to use the `visOpenCopy` flag, but in this case I have another problem - upon subsequent call [Document.ExportAsfixedFormat](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Visio.Document.ExportAsFixedFormat) to save the document in a PDF format in the resulting document, the file properties (title, author, theme and other) are not saved.

I tried separately and in all possible combinations of the flags `visOpenCopy`, `visOpenRo` and `visOpenHidden`. Either a file that is already open in another program does not open in `Documents.OpenEx`, or the properties are not saved to Pdf.

The obvious solution seems to manually copy the file in TEMP before opening, but perhaps someone will tell the solution better.

Tested in Office 2016 and 2013 64bit

add:

```
    // learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.documents.openex
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.OpenEx(Input,           0 or         0 or             0);     // does not open, properties is saved
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.OpenEx(Input,           0 or         0 or visOpenHidden);     // does not open, properties is saved
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.OpenEx(Input,           0 or visOpenRo or             0);     // does not open, properties is saved
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.OpenEx(Input,           0 or visOpenRo or visOpenHidden);     // does not open, properties is saved
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.OpenEx(Input, visOpenCopy or         0 or             0);     // open, properties is absent 
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.OpenEx(Input, visOpenCopy or         0 or visOpenHidden);     // open, properties is absent 
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.OpenEx(Input, visOpenCopy or visOpenRo or             0);     // open, properties is absent 
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.OpenEx(Input, visOpenCopy or visOpenRo or visOpenHidden);     // open, properties is absent 
        
    // learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.documents.addex
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.AddEx(Input, 0,           0 or         0 or             0);   // open, properties is absent
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.AddEx(Input, 0,           0 or         0 or visOpenHidden);   // open, properties is absent
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.AddEx(Input, 0,           0 or visOpenRo or             0);   // open, properties is absent
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.AddEx(Input, 0,           0 or visOpenRo or visOpenHidden);   // open, properties is absent
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.AddEx(Input, 0, visOpenCopy or         0 or             0);   // open, properties is absent
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.AddEx(Input, 0, visOpenCopy or         0 or visOpenHidden);   // open, properties is absent
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.AddEx(Input, 0, visOpenCopy or visOpenRo or             0);   // open, properties is absent
    fVisioDoc := fVisioApp.Documents.AddEx(Input, 0, visOpenCopy or visOpenRo or visOpenHidden);   // open, properties is absent
        
        
    // learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Visio.Document.ExportAsFixedFormat
    fVisioDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(
            visFixedFormatPDF,   // FixedFormat
            Output,       // OutputFileName
```

Comment: Have you tried `AddEx` instead? [Documents.AddEx method (Visio)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.documents.addex)

Comment: I test `AddEx` method, in this case the document is opened anyway but the properties are not saved in pdf anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be correct behavior. If you specify `visOpenCopy`,  then the copy of the document is opened. But the copy does not automatically "inherit" properties such as "subject" or "theme". These are specific to a **document (file)**. So for a new document, they will be cleared, and you may need to set them from scratch. This will happen as well, if you do "Save As..." using the user interface.

Why don't you export the current (already opened) document? Alternatively, the approach you suggested (copy files to temp and then open them from there) sounds reasonable.

Comment: This is not entirely true, I'm talking about the properties of the document, not the file, they are copied when "Save As...".

Comment: This is not entirely true, I'm talking about the properties of the document, not the file, they are copied when "Save As...".
I can't save a document that's already open because it's open by the user and they can already make changes to it.
Copying a document to a temporary file is a "working crutch", if nothing better can come up with you will have to use it.
And yet - other MS Office applications: Word, Excel, PowerPoint, do not avoid such a problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my mistake - the document properties are copied when you do "Save As..", mixed up.